# How to convert NSlayout constraint to integer?

Tags: ios, swift, anchor, nslayoutconstraint

I want to append 20 constant value to nslayoutconstraint, how can I do that ??

```
Let moduleConstraint = module.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:mainScroll.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
moduleConstraint.constant += 20
view.layoutIfNeeded() // refresh the layout
```

Comment: For my case, I am using scroll view I should subtract -=20 other wise it will crop the collection view by 20, anyways, since I did not provide any context your answer is 100% correct.